# Display 3 div's one by one on each click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a help to display 3 div's  one by one when i click each time on `+ Add More` link, also `+ Add more` link to disappear after displaying the 3rd div. please help me

```
<input size="20" id="high_light1" type="text" /> 
 <span><a href="#" id="add"> + Add more</a></span>
 <div style="display:none;"><input size="20" id="high_light2" type="text" /></div>
 <div style="display:none;"><input size="20" id="high_light3" type="text" /></div>
 <div style="display:none;"><input size="20" id="high_light4" type="text" /></div>
```

Note: i don't want to generate new div's, i need make the existing div's `display:block` on each click.

Thanks

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: What's the hard part, attaching an eventlistener for button, getting correct `div` from the document, or maybe hiding the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will use jQuery:

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    $('.toAdd').each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
            return false;
        }
    });
    var i = 0;
    $('.toAdd').each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
            i++;
        }
    });

    if (i == 3) $('#add').hide();
});
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/SFRgz/

Answer (score 2):

Pure Javascript solution (no jQuery dependency):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LBEUT/3/)

```
var divCount = 1;

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = function(){

        if(divCount < 4)
        {
            divCount++;

            var input = document.getElementById("high_light" + divCount);
            input.parentNode.style.display = "";

            if(divCount == 4)
            {
                this.style.display = "none";   
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for a smooth animation, using `fadeIn()` method (see http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), and then make your button disappear with `fadeOut()` method.

If you don't want to use JQuery, try to use `document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden" || "visible";`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how i did it

```
<div class="input-fields">
<input size="20" id="high_light1" type="text" /> 
 <span><a href="#" id="add"> + Add more</a></span>
 <div style="display:none;"><input size="20" id="high_light2" type="text" /></div>
 <div style="display:none;"><input size="20" id="high_light3" type="text" /></div>
 <div style="display:none;"><input size="20" id="high_light4" type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

and js
var i = 0;

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    if(i===0){
        $('.input-fields div:nth-of-type(1)').css("display","block");
        i++;
    }
    else if(i===1){
        $('.input-fields div:nth-of-type(2)').css("display","block");
        i++;
    }
    else if(i===2){
        $('.input-fields div:nth-of-type(3)').css("display","block");
        $('#add').hide();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSGBP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and shortest (with jQuery)

```
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    var div = $(".wrapper div").filter(":hidden");
    var hid = div.size(); // current number of hidden div
    div.first().fadeIn(); // show the first hidden
    hid == 1 ?  $(this).fadeOut() : null; // if we show the last
});
```

... **notice** that I wrapped the hidden `div` in a parent `.wrapper` selector (for specificity).

The advantage of this method is that you don't need to pre-set how many hidden `div` exist

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n3qhv/)**

Comment: @downvoter : thanks, at least prove me wrong or leave a comment.